# 1st order(linear?) polynomial logistic regression, is it a reasonable build? and have only one inflection?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, polynomial

I have been working on a third order polynomial logistic regression
`glmer(optionval ~nt1 +nt2 +nt3 + section:(nt1+nt2+nt3) + (nt1|participant.id), data=current_data, family=binomial,...)`, ps. nts are produced by `nt = poly(tall_merged$timeslice, order=3, raw=T)`.
which works fine for capturing the time-course data. However, the result(summary(), Anova()) are found difficult to interpret (in terms of those interactions with time terms) and my supervisor suggests me running a 1st order one:

```
glmer(optionval ~ nt1 +section:(nt1) +(nt1-1|participant.id) , data=current_data, family=binomial)
```

However, the visualization of the 1st order slope does not look like a inverse logit.
[image]
I think it is probably because our probabilities(data) starts from about 50%, while my supervisor think this is the right half of the inverse logit and the 1st order model should still hold a full inverse logit slope(which I doubt), and the incomplete slope is due to the specification of the formula(I think it is because of the nature of the data and the formula looks quite normal to me).
He is currently thinking about customizing the "link" to produce the desirable slope... which feels so counter-intuitive to me and I doubt if it is the right direction (after all we are gonna return to third order model, it would be wasting time if we head the wrong derection).
Can anyone please suggest if this model is just right, meaning that 1st order model cannot cover full inverse logit, or there is something with the configuration? and how we interpret the result?

Comment: What does "Seconds" mean in your plot and why is it relevant?  This variable does not appear anywhere in your models.  Would it be related to `timeslice`?  How?

Comment: @whuber "Seconds" is just renamed from "timeslice".